# External dependencies gets removed after sbt plugins update

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt

I have my spark project setup with SBT and, whenever I need to add dependencies, I add them in `build.sbt` and run the command
`sbt plugins update`.

Now there are some dependencies that I want to add as `jar` files so I added them in project structure > modules -> Dependencies -> + as jars. After this the dependencies are added and I can import them just fine.

But then, whenever I run `sbt plugins update`, these new dependencies get removed.

Comment: Do you mean you add dependencies through the IDE and it's not persisted in the build.sbt file?

Comment: I don't understand what is the command you run: `plugins` command just lists the currently enabled plugins, `update` is a separate command that resolves and fetches dependencies. So why not just `sbt update`?